# Pass a list as parameter function?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to make a simple function in scheme that finds the largest number in a list.

Here is my code:

```
(define (maximo lista maximo_actual)
    (if (= lista ())
        maximo_actual
        (let* ((primero maximo_actual)
               (segundo (car lista)))
          (if (> primero segundo)
              ((maximo (cdr lista) primero))
              ((maximo (cdr lista) segundo))))))
```

I call the function with this:

```
(maximo (list 6 3 2 8 9) 5)
```

And the program return this:

```
;ERROR: "programas.scm": =: Wrong type in arg1 (6 3 2 8 9)
; in expression: (#@= #@lista ())
; in scope:
;   (lista maximo_actual)  procedure maximo
; defined by load: "programas.scm"
```

I think that there is something wrong with the parameters. I am learning scheme and I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My awnser here is based on [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) (which is based on scheme)

There are a few issues with your program. One, `=` compares numbers, not lists. Secondly `()` is a function with nothing in it, not a list. To create an empty list use either `(list)` or `'()`.  Finally, `((maximo (cdr lista) primero))` has an extra set of parenthesis, which causes the result of `(maximo (cdr lista) primero)` to be executed. However, the result of `(maximo (cdr lista) primero)` is a number.

I think you want something like this, which will return `9` when called with `(maximo (list 6 3 2 8 9) 5)`

```
(define (maximo lista maximo_actual)
    (if (empty? lista)
        maximo_actual
        (let* ((primero maximo_actual)
                (segundo (car lista)))
            (if ( > primero segundo)
                (maximo (cdr lista) primero)
                (maximo (cdr lista) segundo)))))
```

You could also write it using [fold](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html), which is slightly shorter:

```
(define (maxio2 current result)
  (if (> current result)
      current
      result))

(foldl maxio2 5 (list 6 3 2 8 9))
```

Comment: THanks a lot, i am a noob with scheme :P

Comment: Why do you call it "PLT Scheme" if you know that the web site is for "Racket"...?

Comment: It used to be called "PLT Scheme." I thought calling it "Racket" might be a little confusing. But apparently calling it "PLT Scheme" was also confusing, ill edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have four points on your function:

- Your error is because the `=` operator is for numeric comparison, not general equality.  For testing that a list is empty, you normally use the `null?` function.
- Also, for an `if ... then ... else if ...` sort of statement, one normally uses `cond`, not `if`.
- You don't need `let*` here; unstarred `let` will do.  In fact, I'd dispense with the `let` bindings completely for this simple of a function.
- You really should use the conventional Lisp indentation, and bunch up the parentheses.

So, your function, with these changes:

```
(define (máximo lista máximo-actual)
  (cond ((null? lista)
         máximo-actual)
        ((> (car lista) máximo-actual)
         (máximo (cdr lista) (car lista)))
        (else
         (máximo (cdr lista) máximo-actual))))
```

The more advanced way of writing this function, however, is to use `fold-left`, a general list iteration operator that we can define this way:

```
(define (fold-left función valor-corriente lista)
  (if (null? lista)
      valor-corriente
      (fold-left función
                 (función (car lista) valor-corriente)
                 (cdr lista))))
```

`fold-left` corresponds to this common type of `for`-loop in imperative languages:

```
resultado = valor_inicial
for valor in valores:
    resultado = función(valor, resultado)
return resultado
```

Using `fold-left` and a second auxiliary function `máximo-de-dos-valores`, now we have:

```
(define (máximo lista máximo-inicial)
  (fold-left máximo-de-dos-valores máximo-inicial lista))

(define (máximo-de-dos-valores a b)
  (if (> a b)
      a
      b))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more idiomatic Scheme procedure for finding the maximum value in a list:

```
(define (mi-maximo lista)
  (if (empty? lista)
      null
      (maximo (rest lista) (first lista))))

(define (maximo lista maximo-actual)
  (cond ((empty? lista) maximo-actual)
        ((> (first lista) maximo-actual)
         (maximo (rest lista) (first lista)))
        (else (maximo (rest lista) maximo-actual))))
```

Notice that I introduced a new procedure, `mi-maximo` for calling the helper procedure `maximo`, which does all the work. For those cases where you have more than two conditions, it's better to use `cond` instead of a series of nested `if`. Finally, it's preferred to use `empty?` or `null?` for testing if the list is empty. Use the above procedures like this:

```
(mi-maximo '(1 2 3 4 5))
> 5
```

As a final note, a comment on style: in Scheme (and other LISPs for that matter), you close all the parenthesis on the same line, not in separate lines. They're not curly brackets, you know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (max-num lat)
(cond ((null? lat) (error "invalid list of numbers"))
      ((null? (cdr lat)) (car lat))
      (else (max (car lat) (max-num (cdr lat))))))
```

this assumes that 'max' is a build-in procedure which i think most scheme implementions will have.